# Define an involution to show that there is an element of order $2$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$

Tags: number-theory

I am working on the following exercise:

> Let $p$ be an odd prime with $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.Define an involution on $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ which shows that there is an element of order $2$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$.

I know what an involution is, but I do not know how to even start with this exercise. Could you help me?

Comment: Consider $x\mapsto x^{p-2}$

Comment: An involution is a function which is its own (functional) inverse. $x\mapsto -x$ is a common example. As is complex conjugation. Some involutions are also homomorphisms on whatever they act on, and they can be useful some times (not that other involutions cannot also be useful).

Comment: @BrianMoehring: sorry ill do an edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the involution $x\mapsto x^{p-2}=x^{-1}.$

If there is $y$ such that $y\ne1$ but $y=y^{-1}$ (i.e., $y^2=1$), then we are done.

Otherwise, pair each element $x$ in $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^\times$ with $x^{-1}$.

Note that $1$ is self-inverse.

Therefore, since the number ($p-1$) of elements is even,

there must be another element $y\ne1$ that is without a partner so it is its own inverse $y=y^{-1}$;

that means   $y$ is an element of order $2$ in $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^\times$.

Comment: I'm not sure why we have to do this exercise rather than simply identifying the element of order $2$ in $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^\times$ as $p-1\equiv-1$